# Удалить указанный пользователем (через prompt()) символ из строки (по индексу). js

Tags: javascript, строки, slice

Есть такие условия :
Запросить у пользователя произвольную строку - (например: "How much is the fish?").
Запросить у пользователя ID в виде целого числа - (явно привести к числу).
ID соответствует одной из следующих операций (happy pass: считаем что пользователь всегда вводит правильные данные).

```js
let randomString = prompt('Введите произвольную строку:');

let idNumber = Number(prompt('Введите ID: (от 1 до 4)'));

if (idNumber === 1) {
  let fSymbol = prompt('Выберите индекс :');
  let str = randomString;
  let newStr = str.charCodeAt(fSymbol);
  console.log(newStr);

} else if (idNumber === 2) {
  let fSymbol = prompt('Выберите индекс :');
  let str = randomString;
  let newStr = str.slice(0, fSymbol) + str.slice(+1);
  console.log(newStr);
}
```

Пробовал так но ничего не выходит (1 задание решил вроде как) рабочих вариантов так и не нашел хотя действительно искал.

Comment: Хотелось бы напрямую узнать, что означает каждый из ID и куда делись ID = 3 и ID = 4... Вдруг и там будут ошибки, и тогда можно сразу и их исправить :)

Comment: 3 ещё не делал там совсем другое тз

Comment: И все жё, какая операция подразумевается под ID = 1? ID = 2?

Comment: ID = 1 
Узнать unicode значение указанного пользователем (через prompt()) символа (по индексу). (Вроде как сделал )
 ID = 2
Удалить указанный пользователем (через prompt()) символ из строки (по индексу).  Вот с этим и маюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если условие для ID = 2 заключается в том, чтобы удалить символ с выбранным индексом, то могу сказать, что Вы в `str.slice(+1)` забыли поставить, собственно, сам индекс `fSymbol` — из-за этого программа постоянно прибавляет к подстроке до выбранного символа подстроку без первого символа.

<s>UPD: что-то не так, сейчас чиню~</s> Разобрался, забыл к `Number()` всё привести (от автора это дело осталось >.<)

```js
let randomString = prompt('Введите произвольную строку:');

let idNumber = Number(prompt('Введите ID: (от 1 до 4)'));

if (idNumber === 1) {
  let fSymbol = Number(prompt('Выберите индекс :'));
  let str = randomString;
  let newStr = str.charCodeAt(fSymbol);
  console.log(newStr);

} else if (idNumber === 2) {
  let fSymbol = Number(prompt('Выберите индекс :'));
  let str = randomString;
  let newStr = str.slice(0, fSymbol) + str.slice(fSymbol + 1);
  console.log(newStr);
}
```

Comment: let newStr = str.slice(0, fSymbol) + str.slice(fSymbol+1); так оно не работает желаемый символ не убирает (

Comment: @ДмитрийЧебан я уже исправил; дело было в том, что не было `Number()` в чтении индекса, из-за чего программа думала, что мы читаем строку. Не заметил сразу это дело, вот и повис, сейчас вроде бы всё должно идти хорошо :(

Comment: Да всё работает , спасибо вам добрый человек )

Comment: @ДмитрийЧебан пожалуйста. Не забудьте отметить данный ответ как верный, если он Вам помог (галочка слева), на будущее могу посоветовать прочесть материал по ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Отметил , спасибо)))